# JavaFX FXMLLoader fails to load .fxml file

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am currently dealing with javaFX application, my problem is that I keep getting this exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: fx:controller can only be applied to root element.
```

I am using Java 8 and JavaFX version (shown in javafx.properties) is javafx.runtime.version=8.0.65
javafx.runtime.build=b17

Here is some of my LoginView.fxml which I am trying to load:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="320.0" prefWidth="480.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightblue" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.th.officesuite.ui.login.LoginController">
....
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the place where I am trying to load this one:

```
   public FxmlDialog(final DialogController controller, URL fxml, Window owner, StageStyle style, LanguageModel lang) {
    super(style);
    initOwner(owner);
    initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    try {
        loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Class<?> aClass) {
                return controller;
            }
        });
        loader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        URL systemResource1 = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fxml/LoginView.fxml");
        loader.setResources(lang.getBundle());
        loader.setLocation(systemResource1);
        Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) loader.load());
        scene.getRoot().setOnMouseDragged(getMouseDraggedHandler());
        scene.getRoot().setOnMousePressed(getMousePressedHandler());
        setScene(scene);
        fxmlStream.close();
        controller.setDialog(this);            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

URL is checked & verified & not null, LoginView.fxml is visible and right there, where it should be in jar file. 
I would like to also mention that this code was working for me like 2 days ago... till today. I was changing some stuff connected with hibernate in separate module only, should be impacted.
Is there a proper solution to that kind of problem? I know there has been a lot of similiar issues but none of the provided solutions has helped me yet. I tried replacing `<AnchorPane... >` with `<fx:root type...>` but didn't work (it was shouting for that the root is not set...).

Comment: The error message says "fx:controller can only be applied to root element". Is the `AnchorPane` element you showed in the post the root element of the FXML?

Comment: Yes it is the root, first element in my LoginView.fxml

Comment: Is `fx:controller` specified on any other element?

Comment: Actually problem was solved while ago... It was not completely connected with JavaFX, but with using @Autowired object in initialize() method of my java controller... Weird thing but solved.